# Get elements from lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following column of a data frame:

[image]

I get it by doing `dataFrame['opcodes]`.

and I would like to consider only the first 20 and the last 20 elements of each list. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to do the following:

```
dataFrame['opcodes_modified'] =  dataFrame['opcodes'].apply(lambda x: x[:20].append(x[-20:])
```

but i get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

can somebody help me? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Hi, this kind of question should be asked on StackOverflow.
Having said this, don't you miss an `axis=1` parameter in `df.apply` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You logic is correct, it's just the lambda function that is slightly wrong. `.append()` adds a single element to the end of the list, so in your case I guess it adds an element which is a list of 20 elements. You could either use `.extend()` instead, which will do what you want or you can simply write

```py
lambda x: x[:20] + x[-20:]
```